# Why is my ListBox throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

Okay, I was able to create a simple Windows Forms project that reproduces some strange behavior I found. In the designer, make a form with a ListBox (named lbx) anchored Top, Left, Right, and Bottom, and a button (button1).  Now, the Form's code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBoxKaboom
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _initFinished = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._initFinished = true;

            this.Height += 100;
            this.Height -= 50;
            this.Height += 50;
        }

        private void lbx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button1.Enabled = (this.lbx.SelectedItem != null);
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_initFinished)
            {
                int lines = (this.lbx.Height - 4) / this.lbx.ItemHeight;

                this.SuspendLayout();
                while (lines < this.lbx.Items.Count)
                {
                    this.lbx.Items.RemoveAt(this.lbx.Items.Count - 1);
                }

                while (lines > this.lbx.Items.Count)
                {
                    this.lbx.Items.Add("Item " + (this.lbx.Items.Count + 1).ToString());
                }
                this.ResumeLayout();
            }

            base.OnLayout(e);
        }
    }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE THE FOLLOWING INSTRUCTIONS:

**Run this, click any of the items in the list box, and use the arrow keys to move down far enough to cause the list box to scroll**. Kaboom.

Exception (sometimes NullReferenceException and sometimes IndexOutOfBoundsException). Any ideas why? Also, I would think that the items would be in order, but they're not. Is this just a goofy corner case that didn't get handled properly by Windows Forms, or am I doing something wrong?

Stack trace:

> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NativeUpdateSelection()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.EnsureUpToDate()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.get_InnerArray()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.get_SelectedItem()

Comment: please post the exception with stack info.

Comment: I ran the code but don't get an Exception.  What kind of Exception are you getting and where is it thrown?

Comment: Without the exception, I doubt we can help.

Comment: Stack Trace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NativeUpdateSelection()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.EnsureUpToDate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.get_InnerArray()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.get_SelectedItem()

Comment: Oh, and it's a NullReferenceException.

Not a divide-by-zero exception, none of the parameters or args (button1, lbx) are null at the time the exception is thrown.

Comment: Eric J.:  Exception is thrown in lbx_SelectedIndexChanged(...) from the get accessor for SelectedItem.  Use the arrow keys to move down far enough that the box scrolls.

Comment: Even with this extra info, I can't see what would cause an exception... and I can't create one by running your code.  Did you leave out anything, even if it seems unimportant?

Comment: I probably can't post the contents of the designer code (exceeds 600 chars).  I don't know what else.  I found this in the course of developing a larger app.  As soon as I isolated it in a "pet" project, I posted it here.  You're using the arrow keys to move the selection down far enough that the list box has to scroll, right?

Comment: Interesting.  Sometimes (same stack trace as above) it blows up with an IndexOutOfRangeException instead of a null ref.

Comment: This smells like a re-entrancy issue due to modifying layout during a layout event.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, but if that's the case, can you explain what I'm doing wrong, exactly?  Adding and removing items from a list box doesn't modify the ListBox's bounds, so it shouldn't be triggering any subsequent Layout events.  I'm not receiving a stack overflow.

Comment: You're subjecting the ListBox to unnatural acts that it finds intolerable. As a result it is crying out in the only way it knows how - with an exception. However, as you've driven it to madness, its cries are incoherent. Weep for the poor ListBox; it did nothing to deserve such cruelty.

Comment: FMM: You are assuming an implementation detail of the ListBox. If it wants it can invalidate its layout and I suspect that it is. It doesn't have to be a bounds change that causes layout updates - layout can change when showing or hiding scrollbars, adding and removing items and a whole host of other activities - it depends on the implementation of the control.

Comment: @Jeff: either way, I'm NOT getting a stack overflow, which indicates that the condition you've repeatedly warned about isn't happening.  If you really aren't supposed to modify layout within the Layout event, why does Microsoft's own example do exactly that?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout%28VS.80%29.aspx
The given example will raise the Layout event twice, but the second time SetBounds is called, it is essentially a no-op, which won't raise the Layout event because nothing changed, meaning no stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I Copy/Pasted it to an empty Form and get a StackOverflow exception. Looking at it, with manipulation of the Items inside a Layout event I would say you deserve little better.</strike>

I realize this may be a simplification of something else, but there simply are limits to what you can do in a EDS.

My best guess: The ResumeLayout triggers a recursive layout operation. You could try to stem it with a sibling to _initFinished but I would suggest rethinking tour design here.

I copy/pasted wrong, my bad (used layout event).

---

Second try:
based on the two while-loops I would expect the Item strings to be in order, and no vertical scrollbar. It is clear that the listbox is confused,  showing vertical scroll range and with the items out-of-order. So some 'error' is already present in the internals of the Listbox, waiting for a Scroll. I can also reproduce it with the mouse.

A workaround: You should be able to get the desired effect using the Resize event.

Attempt to an explanation: The (unmanaged part of the) Listbox gets confused by (multiple) Add/RemoveAt operations with suspended Layout. The last items are drawn at the wrong place, and the Listbox can't compute pixel-to-item.

Comment: Well, considering the Layout that's being handled isn't the ListBox's, but the Form's, I don't understand how that's even possible (the stack overflow).  Modifying the contents of the ListBox shouldn't affect the parent Form's layout anyway.  See comments on initial post.

Comment: FMM: Modifying the layout of a form child  can cause the parent form's layout to change. I can see how a stack overflow could occur.

Comment: Granted, but modifying the contents of a list box doesn't affect its bounds.

Comment: FMM: That doesn't necessarily matter. You can't rely on it NOT to tell its parent that its layout has changed - that's an implementation detail and it could well do so even if its bounds haven't changed.

Comment: Jeff: still irrelevant - I'm not getting a stack overflow.

Comment: Using the Resize event appears to work in my sample app; let me plug that into my larger app and see how it does.  Stand by...

Comment: OnResize seems to be the cure; I'm still not sure why.  If I understand correctly, SuspendLayout() only suspends layout for the control it's called on, not for its child controls.  For tall hierarchies of Controls, this is an important distinction.  At any rate, the fix works and I've marked yours as the answer.  Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: mackenir: Give me a frickin' break - it's a thrown-together proof-of-concept app.  As such, I have no choice but to at least expect a stab at fixing the problem rather than criticizing the code.  The fix that worked was exactly what you prescribed - do it differently.  If you say what I'm doing is "unusual" then show me a method to achieve the same goal that's less "unusual".  At any rate, the problem is fixed, and I find your advice less than useful.  Must every person who posts on StackOverflow preface themselves with "suggestions for better methods are welcome/not welcome"?

Answer (score 0):

You should not manipulate any GUI elements in the 
constructor, e.g. *this.Height += 100;* in your example. 
Strange things can happen. I have been bitten by this 
several times in legacy code.

Wait until form load time - handle the base.Load event and do the 
height manipulation there.

---

From "[When does Form.Load event get raised?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bf14157f-41b6-45f7-9e4e-7fb46c818b18)":

> Q: "... I need to find out basically
>   what the difference is between 
>   putting code in Load event's handler,
>   versus putting code in  the Form's
>   constructor after the
>   InitializeComponents()  line ..."
>
> A: "The Load event is fired once the
>   control/form has been fully 
>   initialized and has a window handle
>   created. Therefore once  this event
>   has fired it is a fully usable user
>   interface  control. Remember that
>   inside the constructor the actual 
>   window handle for the control/form has
>   not yet been created,  you are only
>   creating C# objects here and inside
>   the  InitializeComponent call."

Comment: Sorry, not buying this.  That's exactly what the Forms Designer does in InitializeComponent().

Comment: @FMM As a computer scientist, whether or not you buy it is irrelevant. Have you tried it? What are the results?

Can you update your question with the results, and any new information you can provide? This will lead to a more complete question and answer for future users to discover.

Comment: Wow, this is some serious post necromancy :) There are some deleted comments here that aren't visible that obscure the full conversation. The advice of "You should not manipulate any GUI elements in the constructor" is bunk. "I don't buy it" could just as easily be read as "that can't be correct." Again, the forms designer does exactly what the answerer suggests in `InitializeComponent()`; hence, the answer is invalid.