# Is it possible to get a null reference error from the ListBox.Items property?

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox, nullreferenceexception

**EDIT 11-20-2009**: This question was posted quite some time ago, but the problem just crept up again this morning; so I'm hoping somebody else can provide some insight (though the answers provided already have been helpful).

Once in a blue moon in our production environment we get a `NullReferenceException` from referencing the `Items` property of a `ListBox` control. I've included some example code below.

The parent form of the `ListBox` in question holds a private `Queue<string>` called `QueuedMessages`. This queue receives new messages on events. On a timer that goes off every 500 ms, the following method gets executed:

```
void DisplayQueuedMessages() {
    lock (QueuedMessages) {
        while (QueuedMessages.Count > 0) {
            string msg = QueuedMessages.Dequeue();
            this.lbxMessages.Items.Insert(0, msg); // NullReferenceException
            if (this.lbxMessages.Items.Count > MAX_LBX_ITEMS) {
                this.lbxMessages.Items.RemoveAt(Me.lbxMessages.Items.Length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, as I've mentioned, this only throws `NullReferenceException` *very* rarely. In several months of using the application it has happened three or four times.

Furthermore, the few times this has happened, it seems either the `ListBox.Items` property or just the `ListBox` itself is mysteriously gone for good: all subsequent methods that add items to the `ListBox` throw exceptions. The only way to recover is to close the application and bring it back up.

Unfortunately, constantly distracted with a million other things to do, I never got around to adding logging before the insertions. I've added the logging now, but it could be a month or more before we see this problem again. In the meantime, any more ideas? What are some possible explanations for this?

I guess my real question is: **Has anyone else ever seen this happen -- accessing a `ListBox` that *did* exist and suddenly getting a `NullReferenceException` -- and were you ever able to figure out why/how to fix the problem?**

Comment: Where are your inserts happening?

Comment: What else accesses Me.lbxMessages.Items?

Comment: The only points in the code where this property is accessed are: `ProcessQueuedMessages()`, which goes off every 500 ms on a `Windows.Forms.Timer` (so, on the GUI thread); and in another method which can happen on certain GUI events that calls `Me.lbxMessages.Items.Clear()`.

Comment: The pattern of Insert and RemoveAt does look like the other SO question I linked to.

Comment: Does this other method on GUI events do any locking?  You should add the same lock, or a new shared lock for any Inserts and Clears (or any other access) of lbxMessages.

Comment: 'Me' in VB is normally the Form object in Winforms.  I assume that's what it is here?

Comment: @Henk: Ha! Yeah, s_hewitt is right -- what an odd mistake... I suppose some vestigial VB snuck into my brain as I was typing it out. I've updated the code to reflect what is actually in the method.

Answer (score 2):

Look deeply in all the code, its very likely that Me.ListBox1 is null.

I once worked on an app built by a third party that code like this that was called only in a specific case and caused an exception during asp.net rendering code ...

```
void ClearItems()
{
   SomeField.Text = "";
   ...
   AnotherField = null; 
   ...
}
```

Also pay attention to the stack trace in the other failures, it would be different if it blows inside the control's method than if it blows in your code.

Answer (score 1):

How sure are you that `Me.ListBox1` hasn't become null? That would be my first guess.

Comment: I'm not sure. What could have made it null given that it is not disposed or set to null in the code?

Comment: Where are you setting this status message? Which events?

Comment: It's definitely instantiated. The program may be running for several hours, with items being added to and removed from the ListBox regularly, up until a point when suddenly this error occurs.

Comment: Try logging whether it's `null` / `Nothing` *just* before you try to access it.

Comment: +1 to comment on logging ... as I said, also check any stack trace you might already have in the other places where it blows by just calling a method i.e. u can tell right away from those if the whole instance is null, as it would blow in your code instead of inside the control in those cases

Answer (score 1):

First, do set a conditional breakpoint and try to find out, and/or write some protective code. I would add something like tis in front of your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Me.ListBox1 != null);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Me.ListBox1.Items != null);
String msg = getStatusMessage(); 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(msg != null);
Me.ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, msg);
```

(I Gues I' mixing VB and C# here, but you get the picture.)

Also make sure the null exception isn't actually happening in an SelectedIndexChanged or similar event.

But it is possible that it really is a ListBox problem, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396043/why-is-my-listbox-throwing-an-exception).

Answer (score 1):

The cause is a System.Windows.Form v2.0 bug I identified this morning (and that is fixed in System.Windows.Form v4.0).

For me it happened while my code adds an `Item` to the `ListBox` while the hosting process is shutting down. The private instance field `ListBox.listItemsArray` is null and this provokes the `NullReferenceException`. I don't know exactly why `ListBox.listItemsArray` is null, but I'd guess it is related to a handle creation problem.

For me the workaround was easy since a `try/catch` was enough because the process is shutting down anyway. You can certainly dig ino the problem with the decompiling Reflector feature as I did:

[image]